# Hibernate generates DDL with KEY instead of FOREIGN KEY in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I designed model in JPA (Hibernate).

Everything works very well.

Then I fired up Workbench and actually looked into schema.

Everything also looks very well on 1st glance (I followed everything from docs and https://vladmihalcea.com/tutorials/hibernate/)

Let's make EER Diagram! Boom - no relations?! Okay, what's up? I look into `Foreign keys` tab in all of my tables - nothing, not a single FK. So i look up DDL - aha! It uses `KEY`. So naturally there are indexes (but those are not FKs, are they?)

[image]

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `changed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `seen` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `uuid` binary(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `issuer_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKhqad2xyyn10pct9vramixbm8n` (`client_id`),
  KEY `FKqs4fxnjxlie9waq3cyav5e06x` (`issuer_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Entity (stripped for brevity):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"order\"")
public class Order
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private UUID uuid;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Client client;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Person issuer;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private ZonedDateTime   creation;
    private ZonedDateTime   changed;
    private boolean         seen;
}
```

In this case, `order` entity is owning relation for `@ManyToOne`s. On the other side I use standard:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "client") // Or issuer
private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
```

My question is - **how do I make Hibernate also generate "real"** `Foreign Keys` that could be reverse engineered into EER Diagram (and generally be "real" as I mentioned).

Comment: How did you tell Hibernate that it should generate the DDLs?

Comment: Not sure what you mean (it was just generated by default). I might add that I am using Spring BOOT so maybe there is some hidden configuration there. But all in all, the only thing I actually coded regarding the model are Entity classes, so what I provided above should give you enough insight. There is nothing else. Those DDL are just present when I looked into "DDL" tab in MySQL Workbench. Hibernate simply doesn't generate Foreign Keys (Keys, work too, but they don't really reflect model into database schema and can't provide me with ER Diagram).

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Selaron answer I'd like to sum up and add some more:

Apparently by default MyISAM DB engine is used [which doesn't support foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-storage-engine.html). Solution is to specify InnoDB that does. You can do this with:

```
hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
```

Additionally since I'm using Spring Boot, this is what you do instead:

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Also if someone would look for custom FK names (instead of random ones from my questions) or more control over FKs:

```
@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_custom"))
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Client client;
```

Comment: Plase add up the information answering your question into a single answer (e.g. by editing this one) and mark your question as answered. People with similar issues will then quickly find this answered question :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have chosen to use MyISAM as storage engine [which does not support foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-storage-engine.html).
You'll have to switch to InnoDB storage engine for example.

In order to explicitly switch to Hibernate MySQL InnoDB Dialect, you cen set `hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb`.

[Found that hint at MySQLInnoDBDialect](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLInnoDBDialect.html)

Comment: This is something I'd probably find far later in development :) I figured InnoDB was default. Thanks!

Comment: I find the same issue with postgres. any solution for that?